# Are Constraints Always Needed - iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

When you are doing the UI for an app via code (in swift), and you are specifying frames for each label, imageview, etc based on other ui elements on the screen, what is the purpose of adding constraints? When should you use constraints and when can you omit them?

Comment: use them when using size classes in your storyboard. if you don't use size classes then you can omit them

Comment: Constraints are also convenient when you need to support rotation. A label should maybe always have 8 points margin leading and trailing (for latin languages etc. "left" and "right"). This is the strength of Auto layout.

Comment: REFRE THIS: https://www.quora.com/Should-I-use-Auto-Layout

Comment: Constraints will continue to work when Apple will create other screen sizes (more or less). Without constraints, you can be certain that your layout will break!

Answer (score 1):

Constraints are used to make your layouts adapt to the current screen size without manually calculating frames. If you simply layout your views in Interface Builder without specifying any constraints, your views will appear to be misplaced on most devices because they don't adapt to the available space.

With constraints, you can easily center views, size them based on the screen edges or the container width and more. This can really save you a lot of headaches because you don't have to think about all the details yourself.

If you don't want to use constraints, you have to calculate frames manually like @Ivan Ičin mentioned before me. Manually calculating frames is how it has been done in the past, but it requires a bunch more manual work than constraints do.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to set constrains if you set frames manually, just ensure that you recalculate them when layout changes (if needed).

This is exactly how the things have been done before constrains, and it is still possible to use the same method if you prefer it.